# How can I get the date range of my available data in influxdb?

Tags: timestamp, influxdb

What query can I issue to obtain the minimum and maximum timestamp of the data set that is available in my influxDB? Or min/max of any other parameter as well.

I have a column called 'time' with the timestamp in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding minimum value on any column the query you can use is

`SELECT min("column_name") FROM "measurement_name"`

& similarly for finding max value you can use

`SELECT max("column_name") FROM "measurement_name"`

Comment: I believe for timestamps in particular, `SELECT first(*) FROM "measurement_name"` is faster